# How don't cut off slides with flexslider in fluid layout

Tags: jquery, carousel, fluid-layout, flexslider

I need some help. I used [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) on my site but there is problem. My site is liquid. It should adjust a margin of li in order to change a quantity of slides in visible area. For instance when resolusion 1366px it be visible 4 item and when resolusion 1024px it be visible 3 item, like [here](http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/), no one has to cut off, just integer number of slides in visible area.
Can you say is it possible with this slider? Because it has options:

```
minItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Minimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when below this.

maxItems: 0,                    //{NEW} Integer: Maxmimum number of carousel items that should be visible. Items will resize fluidly when above this limit.
```

But it doesen't work in my case. Maybe I did something wrong. Here is my calling:

```
var parametrsSlider = {
            animation: "slide",
            animationLoop: false,
            itemWidth: 227,
            itemMargin: 23,
            minItems: 3,
            maxItems: 4,
            controlNav: false,
            move:1
        }
    var exist2 = $("#product-slider").length;
    if(exist2 != 0){
        $('#product-slider').flexslider(parametrsSlider);
    };
    var exist2 = $("#product-slider2").length;
    if(exist2 != 0){
        $('#product-slider2').flexslider(parametrsSlider);
    };
    var exist2 = $("#product-slider3").length;
    if(exist2 != 0){
        $('#product-slider3').flexslider(parametrsSlider);
    };
```

There is [my site](http://business-dev4.alleanza.ru/alfatextil/01_psd_index.html). Thank you in advance

Comment: check the window width when page loads and calculate parameters to pass to the `parametrsSlider` object

Comment: I don't think this is proper, cause user can change the size of window after page loads